# JQuery setTimeout() not working on Mouse Out

Tags: jquery, animation, hover, settimeout

I've got a simple addClass function to add a class on hover so that I can apply a CSS transition to it. I also want the CSS transition to apply when the mouse leaves the container but It doesn't work because I have .removeClass. I realize I can do it with CSS but I'm trying to learn JS.

I've tried the setTimeout like so:

```
    $('.wp-container-20').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).addClass('homeServicesImageHover').bind(this)
        },
        function() {
            setTimeout(
                function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('homeServicesImageHover')
                }, 5000)
        }
    )
```

I can't get that to work.

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems.

1. The second value you pass to `hover()` needs to be a function. You're calling `setTimeout` immediately and passing the return value to `hover()`.
2. `this` means something different when it is in a function called by `setTimeout`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Thank you. I think I have fixed the first problem and I deduce that I need to use the bind() function on the second problem? I'm just unsure where to put it. I assume it needs to be placed with the parent function but I haven't been able to get that working. 

I've edited my question to suit.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this with css not jquery.

Use .yourClass:hover and .yourClass to add CSS correctly. For example the CSS that you should write in .yourClass:hover is the CSS that has the class .imageHover

Also I use this additional class (in your normal class not in :HOVER) that gives some effects on transition

```
.yourNormalClass{
   /* ADDITIONAL CSS TO YOUR NORMAL CLASS */
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;                  
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;                 
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;   
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;          
   transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.yourNormalClass:hover{
   /* Add the CSS apply to ImageHover class here */
}
```

I hope that my info help you :).

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

you are adding and removing the same `class` (ImageHover) and it is not logical. You first add this `class` to the element and then remove it from that same element, so that it has no class at the end!
For transition after mouse leave, you can use `onmouseleave()` event, too.
Good Luck

Comment: Look at this line `function(){ $(this).addClass('ImageHover') },` - there's a comma at the end.  OP is passing two *separate* parameters to the `hover` event, not calling removeClass immediately after addClass